# How to self-host WCF in Windows Forms without another Windows process

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf

I have a Windows application and want to self-host a WCF in it. This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758.aspx) walks you through how to self-host WCF in a console. [Jason Henderson's article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18789/A-Quick-and-Dirty-WCF-Service-and-Client-Using-WCF) demonstrates how to call the service. But the problem is, I don't want to host my service in another Windows process. I want to host it in my client application. Here is my approach:

1. Ctrl + F5 to run the service
2. Add service reference to my client
   application

Then I can start the service in my client like this

```
static void Main()
{
    ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService));
    host.Open();
    Application.Run(new Form1());
    host.Close();
}
```

It works. But what is the best way for doing this?

Comment: Yeah that's pretty much how you do it :-)

Comment: Unless you can tell us how you would define 'best' we have no way of telling you.

Comment: It is so strange that you host WCF within a process and consume it then in the same process. After all, it is in the same process, and you don't need anything like WCF, as those functions can be made protected, internal, or public to be consumed directly.

Comment: It's not strange for development, testing, debugging purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that is exactly what Microsoft recomends:

Hosting in Windows Services
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx

Comment: i didnt mean to post that as an answer since you basically answered your own question... ;)